# Listview from down upwards

Tags: flutter

Well, I am creating a Flutter App that needs different Widgets in the listview, the problem ist that the listview scrolls just downwards and I need it to scroll upwards. I can't find any solution to this.
Can someone maybe help me with it?

I saw once something about reverse Listview but I don't find it anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [`ListView`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView-class.html):

> reverse → `bool`
>
> Whether the scroll view scrolls in the reading direction.

So you can just pass the `reverse` parameter to it:

```dart
ListView(
  // ...
  reverse: true,
  // ...
),
```